# Loading Leadfoot modules in Intern produces an error

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

Leadfoot is installed as part of the Intern framework (`./node_modules/intern/node_modules/leadfoot`). However, when I try to use it as in the documentation (https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/pollUntil.html):

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require) {
    var url = '../../index.html';
    var Command = require('leadfoot/Command');
    var pollUntil = require('leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil');

    registerSuite({
        name: 'Todo (functional)',

        'submit form': function () {
            return this.remote.get(require.toUrl(url))
                .findById('new-todo').then(function (val) {}, function(err) {
                     console.log(err);
                }).click();
        }
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
$ intern-runner config=tests/example_intern
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Error: Attempt to require unloaded module leadfoot/Command
  at contextRequire  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:255:12>
  at module.require.result  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:284:13>
  at </home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/dojo-example/tests/functional/Todo.js:9:16>
  at execModule  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:515:54>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:504:12>
  at Array.map  <native>
  at execModule  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:499:17>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:582:7>
  at guardCheckComplete  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:566:4>
  at checkComplete  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:574:27>
```

Could someone explain how to use Leadfoot correctly in functional tests?

Inserting the suggested changes:

```
$ intern-runner config=dojo-example/tests/intern
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Error: Failed to load module leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil from /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/life-tracker3/leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil.js (parent: dojo-example/tests/functional/Todo)
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:757:12>
  at <fs.js:207:20>
```

at Object.oncomplete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the leadfoot module id's in the `define` array rather than `requiring` them.

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Command',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, Command, pollUntil) {
```